# What does Rechambering Accuracy mean?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-ii

I've just unlocked an attachment for SP-R 208 that increases Rechambering Speed (increased speed of bolt-action). As a frontline sniper myself, the increased speed of Rechambering Speed sounds good to me, but I don't understand what Rechambering Accuracy means. The description says that "Affects recoil control" and it lowers accuracy stats, but I don't see any difference of recoil while using, nor accuracy. So then what does it changes?[image]

Comment: Maybe when you are ADSing, the scope/sight moves more when you eject the bullet and load another?

Comment: That might be it, I'll try it when I get to home to see if I can catch any difference. Luckily this CoD has a dedicated firing range to test weapons (didn't notice until now though, saw an article for that just now).

Comment: Actually great question and I think Timmy Jim is correct, but there is no entry anywhere describing this CON.
Definitely something they need to build up on their website or describe it in-game!

Comment: I've tested it, but I couldn't see much of a difference... anyway, here's [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ufJ5s6qRGJQ), let me know if you find anything. For reference, I've used highest zoom scope I have (8.0x) to see more difference, but here we are...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using attachments that affect rechambering accuracy vs rechambering speed it basically boils down to your playstyle with that weapon. Not using either gives no benefit or detriment to rechambering.

Speed = The next shot is readied quicker. The detriment(losing accuracy) is your aim will be off. (this is useful for run n gunners)

Accuracy = After Rechambering, your aim/accuracy will be more consistent with where it was previously. The detriment (losing speed) is your shot will take longer to rechamber. (this is useful for snipers)

The differences can be quite minute, but tuning can make it them bigger.

Important to note: Aiming Stability will also play a huge part if you are testing this while ADS. A bipod would help in eliminating that variable.

Comment: So then Rechambering accuracy essentially mean... increased recoil/gun kick by rechambering?

Comment: It's not really recoil or kick in the usual sense, but yes you can look at it like that.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently CoD:MW2 features so much mechanical detail, that under certain circumstances you can fail to reload (depending on the gun individual single bullet rechambering or briefly misaligning the entire magazine), the hand flinches and another attempt to reload is made. [Someone recorded an example here.](https://www.tiktok.com/@offbreezy/video/7163150639999126830?is_from_webapp=v1&item_id=7163150639999126830)

Still needs to be proven solidly while the questionable terminology of "rechambering" vs. "reloading" remains.

Edit: After playing for another few hundred hours, I am very certain, that my weapon didn't fire at all a few times, when it was expected to. A misfire after a changed mag. Maybe this is related.

Comment: I actually think I recall seeing this mechanic. So essentially it boils down to "reload speed"

Comment: That could possibly it, however in my experience while using SP-R 208 with the attachment, I never encountered second attempt of rechambering (in other word, never failed). I almost always using this gun, according to Steam my playtime is 104 hours already, I think about 80 to 90 hours or so are with this attachment. Perhaps that only happens on Warzone/DMZ, or I'm just lucky. That video doesn't have what I wanted to know (though the information itself is very interesting), so if you find anything about the behavior about this attachment, please let me know. Meanwhile I'll also seek for it.

Comment: I think it's easy to overlook in the heat of battle. When that low chance of failure is hit, it also doesn't heavily change the total reloading duration. I personally would probably rather look at the surroundings or minimap after hitting the reload button, instead of directly at the weapon model.

Comment: Rechambering doesn't involve reloading (except when you're completely dry), it happens when you shoot the gun. I try to shoot the guns as fast as possible, so if the operator misses chambering it's massive change. Since you mentioned it, I tried to shoot the guns with the attachment 10minutes straight in the firing range. Never failed to rechamber. Then I thought that this kind of mechanic couldn't be triggered at firing range so I went to custom and no changes. Again, please let me know if you find a video that shows this exact mechanic.

Comment: I'm sorry, I chose inaccurate wording. As far as I can guess and how I meant it, "rechambering" would only be accurate for weapons, that are loaded with individual bullets (even then my term 'rechambering' is questionable). It seems that for guns with magazines, the operator briefly misaligns the entire magazine against the shaft, causing a very short delay, before succeeding to insert the mag.

Comment: That is very normal if someone wants to reload magazine if the guns are bolt action (automatic weapons do that automatically). As far as I know they're not rechambering, it's reloading. IF "rechambering accuracy" affects reloading then the description is false. I know MW2 is a bit of luckluster, but they didn't fail to write description, AFAIK. As I said, rechambering is when you shoot the bolt action weapons (in this case, SP-R 208), the operator pulls bolt handle and ejects casing, and undo the pulled bolt to feed next bullet from magazine.

Comment: Ah, and if you tactical reload it (meaning when at least one bullet is remaining in the magazine), the operator doesn't pull the bolt, since it doesn't needed (operator doesn't have to pull the bolt since bullet still remains in chamber), so rechambering doesn't happen. They just unloads their magazine and loads new one. When you're completely dry, they pulls bolt to eject casing, and to feed bullet from newly inserted magazine.

Comment: Now that I saw your edit (sorry for being late), I think that happened because: You shot your gun and reloaded right after shooting, not giving your operator to rechamber next ammo. This causes, after you reload your magazine, your operator to rechamber ammo. For that moment, you cannot shoot your next shot, since you don't have ammo in your weapon's chamber, and that is very normal and realistic.